# jQuery: Need to know which option that has been selected/de-selected on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectlist

I have a problem with my selectlist in jQuery.
I have made a "Select All" option with value "-1", and when I click it, all the options is marked as selected.
However, when I want to de-select the "Select All" option, I can't figure out how to know if I actually has de-selected the "Select All"-option.

Anyone knows how I can do this?

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selectlist" name="selectlist" checkedAll="false">
     <option id="all" value="-1">Choose all</option>
     <option value="1" choice="true">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2" choice="true">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3" choice="true">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#selectlist").live("change", function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "-1") {
        var isChecked = $("#selectlist").attr("checkedAll");
        if (isChecked == "false") {
            $("#selectlist").attr("checkedAll", "true");
            $("#selectlist option[choice='true']").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#selectlist").attr("checkedAll", "false");
            $("#selectlist option[choice='true']").each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("selected");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I saw some errors as I edited the names of the ID's before I posted it here to make it easier to read. Have fixed the code parts in the question now!

Comment: Why can't you just use Choose All as an option, and not try to flag the others as selected?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I want all the other options to be checked so the users could see that they are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not quite a concrete solution to the problem above, but I came across the same situation some time ago.

The solution was custom plugin: **[jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)** by **Eric Hynds**

I suggest you give it a try ;)

Comment: I've used that plugin on other projects, but in this situation I'm working with a mobile UI, so it's a little bit too small for using touch :(

Comment: Ah, I see... back to square one :)